# Ruby on Rails thinking-sphinx has many through indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, thinking-sphinx

Cheers! I have `tour` model with these associations:

```
  has_many :tour_in_the_countries
  has_many :country, :through => :tour_in_the_countries
```

And in tour_index.rb

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :tour, :with => :active_record do
  indexes :title
  indexes :preview
end
```

How to add to index country's name in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
indexes tour_in_the_countries.country.name, :as => :countries
```

Comment: Also: I would personally rename the `has_many :country ...` to `has_many :countries ...` - Rails is smart enough to pick up you mean the `country` association on TourInTheCountry

Comment: I'm sorry, I built index and I though it's all ok, but when I try to search: `Tour.search :conditions => {:countries => 'Australia'}` it returns me no_method error with `undefined method conditions= for #<MetaSearch::Searches::Tour:0x007f98c125bb90>`

Comment: It looks like you've got both Thinking Sphinx and MetaSearch in your Gemfile - do you need both? If so, I think placing thinking-sphinx after meta_search in your Gemfile should ensure they get loaded in the correct order.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using active-admin gem which is using metasearch!

Comment: Just make sure `activeadmin` is before `thinking-sphinx` in your Gemfile and it should work fine (I've got several projects that use both).